# Setting database engine collation during SQL Server installation

Tags: sql-server, installation, default, collation, database-engine

I want to install SQL Server but I don't want to use default database engine collation defined during setup(there is polish collation). I know how to change it during setup but I need clear English (which is not on the list).

It is safe to install server with random collation and the try to change database engine collation?

Comment: I would personally install the instance with the correct collation first. Changing the collation afterwards is much harder than getting it right at the start.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't select english collation from the list ;/

Comment: @Redzix, what do you mean by not able to select an English collation? A Latin1_General collation is appropriate for english languages. Consider using `Latin1_General_CI_AS` and standardize on the same collation for all of your instances, if possible.

Comment: Resolved, thanks :)